# Laravel scout Algolia Is there anyway to remove an item from the search index without removing it from the local db

Tags: laravel, algolia, searchable, laravel-scout

I know that I can remove an item from the search index by:

```
$order = App\Order::find(1);
$order->delete();
```

or

```
App\Order::where('price', '>', 100)->unsearchable();
```

But I only want to remove it from the search index/Algolia and still keep it in my local DB, is this possible?

Comment: you can use soft delete for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second snippet is correct, `unsearchable` will remove the record from Algolia but keep it in your local DB.

```
App\Order::find(1)->unsearchable();
```